# Not sure how to change these lightbulbs. What is this lighting system?

Tags: electrical

Bought a flat and found these amazing recessed lights.

The bulbs can be set to warm, cool or dim with one selector switch.

The bulbs cannot be twisted out.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Could you post a picture?

Comment: Can you pull the bulb straight out (maybe with a bit of side-to-side wiggle)? Also, make/model of the light fixtures and/or pictures are incredibly helpful. Please [edit] your post to include this info.

Comment: You say they can not be changed but you do not say if they need to be changed ? Are they not functioning, if not, are you sure it is the bulb that has failed ? AND What exactly do you mean by Bulb, the round thing inside ? Can you access the inside of the fixture ?

Comment: What's motivating you to want to change these? It looks like they are unitary LED fixtures (integrated emitters) and would have to be replaced as an entire fixture (instead of being able to swap emitter units)

Comment: Several no longer emit any light. They are 12 feet up and I’ve bought a ladder to reach.

Answer (score 3):

### What is this “bulb” of which you speak?  :)

The “multiple color temperature” switch indicates this is LED lighting.

LED is a semiconductor technology for making light.
Like most semiconductors, they are extremely reliable and do not wear out.  (Calamities do happen, but usually, they happen to the support circuitry; I’m looking at you, capacitors.)

The computer industry learned in the 1970s that when semiconductors are socketed, *the socket itself* becomes far-and-away the most common point of failure. As such, 99% of semiconductors are soldered to the circuit board, to eliminate that #1 point of failure.

LED emitters are no exception. They will outlast you and I, and there is no earthly reason to socket one.  (Mind you the LED *fixture*, or screw-in Edison replacement “bulb” which is a mini-fixture of its own, may not have that longevity... but when it fails, it’ll be capacitors in the electronic driver failing or the RoHS solder crystallizing, not the LED emitter failing.

So there is no reason for an LED emitter to be removable.

In particular, noting that the color temp switch is outside the emitter area, it goes without saying those things are hard-wired to each other.